# Django how I can get all objects to the list from db?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to use a "ArticleBlock", and it must have some "Articles"

I wrote next models

```
class ArticleBlock(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "articleblock"
    articleBlockName = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Articles(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "articles"
    articles_titel = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    articles_text = models.TextField()
    articles_date = models.DateTimeField()
    articles_main = models.ForeignKey(ArticleBlock)
```

The first question?
Is it correct? if I want bind many articles to one some block?
In view.py I have next:

```
def article_theme(request, articleblock_id=2):
    return render_to_response('article_theme.html', 
   {"ArticleBlock_name": ArticleBlock.objects.get(id=articleblock_id), 
   'articles_list':list(Articles.objects.filter
   (articles_articleblock_id=articleblock_id))})
```

I want get a list() with articles, to sort random them.
How I can get the list from db?

Answer (score 0):

1) yes it is correct
2) on the official docs says that list(Query object) should return a list with the results, is it not working?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/

and just a suggestion i always declare the variables before sending to the response like this:

```
def article_theme(request, articleblock_id=2):
    ArticleBlock_name = ArticleBlock.objects.get(id=articleblock_id)
    articles_list = list(Articles.objects.filter(articles_articleblock_id=articleblock_id))
    context = {
        "ArticleBlock_name": ArticleBlock_name, 
        "articles_list":articles_list
    }

    return render_to_response('article_theme.html', context)
```

for better reading.
NOTE: putting the variables in the context dict doesnt change the access names in the templates you still access those variables with {{ArticleBlock_name}}

Comment: <QuerySet [<Articles: Articles object>, <Articles: Articles object>, .... and I can't make:     random.shuffle(articles_list)